# Google Api авторизация изнутри скрипта

Tags: javascript, google-oauth2

Как авторизоваться в google api изнутри javascript скрипта, введя почту и пароль? Сделать авторизацию через всплывающее окно авторизации гугла у меня получилось, но этот скрипт ориентирован чисто на бек, и мне нужно, чтобы авторизация происходила без участия пользователя. Есть варианты?

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Заходите в [кабинет](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard), выбираете проект.

**2)** В левом меню нажимаете 'Библиотека' или по этой [ссылке](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library), там выбираете нужные API и для каждого нажимаете "ВКЛЮЧИТЬ".

**3)** В левом меню нажимаете 'Учетные данные' или по этой [ссылке](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials).

Там нажимаете "Создать учетные данные" > "Ключ API".
После создания ключа переходите в настройки ключа, можно через адресс https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/key/**<Ваш ключ>**

В "Допустимые API" выбираете нужное API

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь можете использовать этот API ключ в выбранном API.

Например, вот как использовать в [client library javascript](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/)

```
gapi.client.init({
  'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
  ...
}).then(...)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но все равно требуется авторизация пользователя при запуске скрипта, если он ранее не авторизовался. Как-то можно ввести данные изнутри скрипта?

Comment: В самом скрипте указывать логин и пароль, такое никто не делает. Если Вам нужно чтобы данные пользователя были у вас на фронте, то в гугл есть отдельная авторизация для этого, [вот тут](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent) все детально описано. Там есть демонстрация в разделе "Complete example", пользователю предлагается выбрать аккаунт после чего скрипт получает данные.